# Batch Conversion in Terminal with Inkscape

Tags: svg, terminal, batch-processing, inkscape

I'm trying to batch convert svg files to pdf using inkscape.

One by one the following command works perfectly:

```
inkscape -f /dir/to/input.svg -A /dir/to/output.pdf
```

When I try the following:

```
for i in *.svg; do inkscape -f "${i}" -A "${i}.pdf";done
```

I get this error:

```
** (inkscape-bin:6844): WARNING **: Can't open file: 2200.svg (doesn't exist)
```

Any help would be appreciated!